# Android Option Menu and Two Pane Layout

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I would like to add action menu  above first fragment, not above second fragment. 
I have no idea how to implement. Below is the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Please help how to implement separate action menu for each fragment in two-pane layout like the following image from internet.

Thank you. I used Toolbar from support lib.

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: you need make actionbar in activity to hold 'serach' icon

Comment: I know it's almost a year this was asked..but still would like to ask that "did you found out answer to your question"?Because i am looking out to implement similar separate menus in two pane layout..